# Prettier AutoFormatting error for typescript and javascript mixed project

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I am **adding typescript to an existing javascript project**. It is a large scale project, so I decided converting the project to typescript step by step.

This is my eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    'airbnb-typescript/base', // Airbnb style guide
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended', // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and displays prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint' // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module' // Allows for the use of imports
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
      }
    }
  },
  rules: {
    // some rules here
  },
  plugins: ['prettier']
};
```

The problem is on save, prettier should format my code. but It doesn't

here is the output of my Prettier log

```
["ERROR" - 12:34:20 PM] Error formatting document.
Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'CLIOptions': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
```

I tried running `npm install @typescript-eslint --save-dev`. but no luck

How to optimize my eslintrc to fix this issue. 
Reminder: I should be able to use this configuration with both typescript and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the vscode prettier extension fixed my problem. That extension was conflicting with my prettier setup. hope that the extensions develop team will fix this issue soon.